# tcpdf - background image - CakePdf

Tags: cakephp, tcpdf

I am trying to setup pdf generation with a background image using CakePdf and the TcPdf engine. I have managed to get the image onto the background using the following settings:

```
// set background image
$img_file = APP . 'webroot/img/BC_Letterhead.jpg';
$TCPDF->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
```

The problem is the image does seem to cover the full background. It seems to be about 1 inch short to the right and about 2 inches short of the bottom of the page. The image I am using is the correct size (I double checked it)

Could this be a margin issue or similar?

Thanks

Comment: Please tell me what is APP? its website path or folder path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work more or less with the following code. The only issue is I still have about 1cm at the bottom without the background image covering it, the width is fine.

```
        // -- SET BACKGROUND IMAGE ------------------------------>
        $TCPDF->SetFooterMargin(0);

        // get the current page break margin
        $bMargin = $TCPDF->getBreakMargin();

        // get current auto-page-break mode
        $auto_page_break = $TCPDF->getAutoPageBreak();

        // disable auto-page-break
        $TCPDF->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0);

        // set background image
        $img_file = APP . 'webroot/img/BC_Letterhead.jpg';
        $TCPDF->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 225, 305, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);

        // set the starting point for the page content
        $TCPDF->setPageMark();
        $TCPDF->setPrintFooter(false);
        // END BACKGROUND MODS -------------------------------->
```

Comment: you will not have the whole page with this solution

Answer (score 10):

The point is to remove header and footer, setting margins to zero and auto page break to false.

For example, to print an image covering a full A4 page:

```
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// remove default header/footer
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0, true);

// set auto page breaks false
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');

// Display image on full page
$pdf->Image('background.jpg', 0, 0, 210, 297, 'JPG', '', '', true, 200, '', false, false, 0, false, false, true);

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('page.pdf', 'I');
```

There's also an example using a custom header in the documentation:

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_051.phps

Comment: All true about removing header, footer, setting margins to sero etc, but another key thing for me was the need to set the resize param to true as is show in the last param in the example above from Juangui Jordán.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
//Page header
public function Header() {
    // get the current page break margin
    $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
    // get current auto-page-break mode
    $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
    // disable auto-page-break
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
    // set background image
    $img_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'pozadina.jpg';
    $this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 98, 59, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
    // restore auto-page-break status
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
    // set the starting point for the page content
    $this->setPageMark();
}
}
$pdf = new MYPDF('L', 'mm', array(59,98));
$pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'D'); //To force download
```